# Transforming scale ruins the scrollbars?

Tags: css, css-transforms

In CSS, we can do a nice *scale* effect on images, without hassling too much with their *width* and *height* attribute:

```
transform: scale(2);
```

To reach a common goal, it's better to adjust the *origin* too:

```
transform-origin: center;
```

This way the image will be scaled while keeping its origin at the center, so it will be more natural to the human eye.

However, if we put this image (and why shouldn't we do) into a wrapper, this seems ruining the scrollbars.

Consider this image:

[image]

This is a fairly big image, and I put it into a fixed sized wrapper.

After applying also the scaling CSS, scrollbars are ruined, i.e. I can't move upwards nor left, so the left and top parts of the image are cut, while we can move downwards and right without issues.

Here is the very simple JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thyzog8u/

Can I somehow easily overcome on this limitation of using `scale` with CSS?

[image]

```css
.image_wrap {
   width:400px;
   height:200px;
   overflow:auto;
}
.image_wrap img {
    transform: scale(2);
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_wrap">
    <img src="http://www.alessioatzeni.com/CSS3-Cycle-Image-Slider/images/img_1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`scale` and `transform` in general doesn't affect the layout flow. You have to use `width` and `height` + Scrolling with JavaScript for this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let scrollElement = document.querySelector('.image_wrap');
  scrollElement.scrollLeft =  (scrollElement.scrollWidth -    scrollElement.clientWidth ) / 2;
  scrollElement.scrollTop =  (scrollElement.scrollHeight -    scrollElement.clientHeight ) / 2;
});
```

```css
.image_wrap {
   width:400px;
   height:200px;
   overflow:auto;
}
.image_wrap img {
    width: 1360px; /* 680 (image width) * 2 */
    height: 640px; /* 320 (image height) * 2 */
}
```

```html
<div class="image_wrap">
    <img src="http://www.alessioatzeni.com/CSS3-Cycle-Image-Slider/images/img_1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

You can also use JavaScript to get a dynamic image size.

Credit for scrolling half way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64264419/9977151